# custom view with extra string parameters in constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I passs multiple strings into custom views constructor in android

```
public DrawSomethingView(Context context, String originalBgPath, String pattern) {}
```

and why it forces to do it like that ?

```
public DrawSomethingView(Context context, AttributeSet S){
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the standard constructors so the framework knows how to inflate them, e.g. from an XML layout. If you put a `DrawSomethingView` in your layout, how would it know what to pass for `originalBgPath` etc? You also need a `Context` and `AttributeSet` at a minimum to call one of the `View` superclass's constructors. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/custom-views/create-view)

That link also tells you how to create your own attributes, that you can add to the XML for your custom view, and pull out the data in the class itself. So you could add your strings as part of the XML definition. If you want to set them programmatically instead, you'll need to add some properties you can set (which you could also set when you read those attributes).

But there's no way to force them to be set, since you can't create your own version of the constructor that requires them (and the framework wouldn't have values to provide anyway). So you'll need to handle the possibility they're missing (e.g. nullable properties, default values), and maybe write a builder function that you can call from your code, that *does* require those values and creates and sets up the custom view before passing it back to you.